# How to create a double headed arrow in matplotlib (with text)

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, arrows

I would like to plot a double headed arrow in a matplotlib plot.
And add at the middle of it some text.
Here is a MWE in python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,10,11,11,12,13,14,15,16]
y = [10,8,6,4,2,0,10,8,6,4,2,0,10,8,6,4,2,0]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,3.5))
ax = fig.gca()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.arrow(6.5, 0, 0, 10,length_includes_head=True,width=0.1)
plt.show()
```

This is what I get currently
[image]

And this is what I would like to obtain

[image]

Comment: https://scipython.com/book/chapter-7-matplotlib/examples/arrow-styles/

Comment: So what you want to obtain is not even an arrow but a big curly bracket...?

Comment: I'll live with an arrow, and go for the solution proposed by Joe. Thank you Joe.